# Transitions between controllers within navigation stack with custom navigation bars

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have three controllers, each with different style on navigation bar

Controller A: white navigation bar, transparent status bar (so that the content is visible), achieved through custom bg image on navbar

[image]

Controller B: white navigation bar, white status bar, achieved through custom bg image on navbar

[image]

Controller C: navigation bar is hidden, there is just custom transparent view with buttons

[image]

Standard use case is A > B > C and back again

The problem is that there is just one navigation bar object and when I update it's visibility or background image, it applies for all view controller. So when I go from A to B, status bar turns white during transition. When I go from B to C, nav bar disappears even while B is still visible (or after it is gone, depending on whether I change navbar in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear).

My goal is to have "separate" navbar style for all controller so that it won't change during transition, but the new controller slides in with it's own navbar while the old one goes away with his navbar style untouched.

Is something like this even possible without using my own UINavigationController implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. UINavigationController has `navigationBarHidden` property. Set it to true to hide the navigation controller holding the controller A, B and C.

Then add a navigation bar or a button to each child view controller (A, B and C) to be pushed/popped with the view controller.

You may need to call `popViewControllerAnimated` when the back buttons of B and C are tapped.

**Structure:**

```
UINavigationController (with navigationBarHidden set to true)
|
+- UIViewController A
|  |
|  + UINavigationBar
|
+- UIViewController B
|  |
|  + UINavigationBar
|
+- UIViewController C
   |
   + UIButton
```

Comment: Is that A's navigation bar something I need to create myself or fake with view? When I set navigationBarHidden to true then I don't see any navigation bar anywhere

Comment: Yes, you have to create and place a navigation bar to A's subviews. Edited the answer for clearer explanation.

Comment: I went with similar solution. I did not hide the navbar, I just set it's background to transparent image and created custom view underneath it with desired image. This way I get what I want, but I keep navbar's functionality (like back buttons and stuff), best of both worlds. I am waiting for few days to see if there are any unforeseen problems with this solution